# Why isn't this pandas Boolean indexing code on numeric columns working?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, nan

I have a `Pandas` `Dataframe` where different (numeric) columns have a different number of data points and the index is a time series. I'd like to return a new `DataFrame` of rows only where my two columns of interest both have values. I've tried using [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) but the new `DataFrame` doesn't contain any values, implying there are no matches. However, this isn't the case.

This is the code I tried, it doesn't produce any errors but the resulting `DataFrame` is empty:

```
sve2_all.resample('D', how='mean')
sve2_hg = sve2_all[(sve2_all['Rim_GWT'] == True) & (sve2_all[' Q l/s'] == True)]
sve2_hg.describe()
```

Comment: *"different (numeric) columns have a different number of data points"* => **some of your values in each column are NaN**. So you want to write an expression to filter out/select only the rows with non-NaNs in both numeric columns. You have to actually figure out the function to do this, you can't just compare a numeric to Boolean 'True' and expect that to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `== True` does not check for "having values" but that those values have the value True (which is the same as 1). That is, you're looking at only those rows where `sve2_all['Rim_GWT'] == 1.0` and `sve2_all[' Q l/s'] == 1.0` (it's not so surprising that this would be no rows).

Perhaps you want to check for not being NaN using pd.notnull:

```
sve2_all[sve2_all['Rim_GWT'].notnull() & sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull()]
```

Comment: I tend to prefer using the methods, i.e. `sve2_all["Rim_GWT"].notnull()`, but that's only a matter of style.